# XElement.CreateNavigator vs XDocument.CreateNavigator

Tags: c#, xml

Given this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>  
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>      
  <mySection>
    <NetworkShare folder="\\myFolder\v1" />        
  </mySection>  
</configuration>
```

Following code does not work (gives blank output):

```
var navigator = XElement.Load(ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None).FilePath).CreateNavigator();
            var q = navigator.Select("/configuration/mySection/NetworkShare");
            if (q.Count == 1) // q.Count is 0
            {
                q.MoveNext();
                Console.WriteLine(q.Current.GetAttribute("folder", navigator.Prefix));
            }
```

But this code works (correctly prints out folder):

```
var navigator = XDocument.Load(ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None).FilePath).CreateNavigator();
            var q = navigator.Select("/configuration/mySection/NetworkShare");
            if (q.Count == 1) // q.Count is 1
            {
                q.MoveNext();
                Console.WriteLine(q.Current.GetAttribute("folder", navigator.Prefix));
            }
```

Is this a bug in .net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that queries on an `XDocument` are at a different context than those of an `XElement`.  For an `XDocument`, it represents the entire document.  It's child is the root element (`configuration` in this case).  For an `XElement`, it represents the element itself.

So when you loaded the file through `XElement.Load()`, queries will be relative to that element.  Loading the file through `XDocument.Load()`, queries will be relative to the document.

So when you queried `/configuration/...`, since for the `XElement` you are currently at the `configuration` element, it clearly doesn't have a `configuration` child so the query yields nothing.  For the `XDocument` on the other hand, it works as expected.

Comment: thanks. using XElement, the correct way to parse is to use var q = navigator.Select("/mySection/NetworkShare");